# How can I read Chinese characters sent using messaging?

Tags: cyanogenmod, sms

My mother sends texts in mostly Chinese due to her lack of knowledge on the English language. However, it seems like it can only be seen on iDevices, and not my Android running CyanogenMod 10.2. The text simply isn't displayed, only the English words are shown. Is it possible for me to display said Chinese text, preferably without installing mods?

Comment: Do the chinese characters appear correctly in instant messaging apps?

Comment: No, default messaging app shows it as spaces, skype shows it as rectangles.